# Google Latitude and OAuth Signed requests

Tags: perl, oauth, google-latitude

I've written a script that authenticates against Google's OAuth API for Latitude, using [Net::OAuth](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3A%3AOAuth). It correctly authenticates (as I can successfully fetch data out of the API). However, when I try to [add an historical entry](http://code.google.com/apis/latitude/v1/using_rest.html#InsertingHistory), I get a `401 Unknown authorization header` response. I'm using the following code:

```
my $location_data = $json->encode(\%data);

$request = Net::OAuth->request("protected resource")->new(
    consumer_key => $c_key,
    consumer_secret => $c_secret,
    token => $token,
    token_secret => $token_secret,
    verifier => $verifier,
    request_url => 'https://www.googleapis.com/latitude/v1/location',
    request_method => 'POST',
    signature_method => $s_method,
    timestamp => time,
    nonce => &nonce(),
    extra_params => {
        key => $s_key
    }
);

$request->sign;

$ua->default_header("Authorization", $request->to_authorization_header);
$ua->default_header("Content-Type", "application/json");

my $res = $ua->post('https://www.googleapis.com/latitude/v1/location?key=' . $s_key,
    Content => $location_data);
```

All of the variables are used in the fetch portion of the API, so I know those are all ok. I'm not sure if I'm using the correct URL to post against, and I've tried what's in the sample above, as well as `$request->to_url`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth with the Latitude API team, it was determined that this error comes from the fact that the `Content-Type` is not actually being set to `application/json`. Changing the above code to:

```
$ua->default_header("Authorization", $request->to_authorization_header);

my $res = $ua->post('https://www.googleapis.com/latitude/v1/location?key=' . $s_key,
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    Content => $location_data);
```

And everything works as expected.